# Move drag handle when dragging UIButton

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview, uibutton, uiimage

I have a view that has UIButtons that respond to dragging events.  That all works fine, the issue is that the button is only 70X70 and the image for the button gets largely covered up with your finger when dragging (the process is that the user drags the image (UIButton) onto a target area on a view).  Is there a way to offset the drag handle so it isn't the center point of the UIButton?  Ideally I would want it to be the top right of the image for the UIbutton, because the bottom left is the area I care most about the user seeing.

EDIT: Here is the code I am using to handle the touch (drag) events:

```
- (IBAction) imageTouch:(id) sender withEvent:(UIEvent *) event
{
    UIButton *thisButton = (UIButton *)sender;

    CGPoint centerPoint = [[[event allTouches] anyObject] locationInView:self.view];
    UIControl *control = sender;
    control.center = centerPoint;

    UIColor *selColor = [WebImageOperations getColorFromImage:self.targetImageView.image atX:point.x andY:point.y];

    NSInteger thisScore = [Scoring scoreFromUIColor:selColor withArrow:thisButton.tag];

    switch (thisButton.tag) {
        case 10:
            arrow10Score = thisScore;
            self.score10Label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", arrow10Score];
            break;
        case 12:
            arrow12Score = thisScore;
            self.score12Label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", arrow12Score];
            break;
        case 14:
            arrow14Score = thisScore;
            self.score14Label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", arrow14Score];
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

    NSInteger totalScore = arrow10Score + arrow12Score + arrow14Score;
    self.totalScoreLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", totalScore];
}
```

Comment: maybe https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIButton/contentEdgeInsets or https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIButton/imageEdgeInsets

Comment: How is that comment constructive at all?  I know most of the UIButton properties and methods.  This kind of comment is totally worthless unless you can provide a code sample indicating that using some method on that class will help with the question I asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is possible.  If someone comes across this question and has a solution, please post it here and I will mark that answer as the correct one.